# Store custom image http call with Multer in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, http, buffer, multer

I have HTTP call with Buffer image inside from NodeJS *Server 1* (run at `localhost:5000`) to NodeJS *Server 2* (run at `localhost:5001`)

There are the *Server 1* axios call:

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:5001/', {
  buffer: fileBuffer,
  ...otherData //
})
```

I read that Multer gets the image from req.files, but in my case they arrive as req.body.buffer

How can i do?

Comment: You would have to show us your server code that uses multer for us to have any idea how to help.  I'm guessing there's an issue with how multer is configured on your server.

Comment: On second thought, multer is for `multipart/form-data` data, but you're not sending `multipart/form-data` data with your axios code.  You're just sending a single buffer of data which would just be in the body, not in a multipart container.

Comment: Hi @jfriend00 thanks for the advice, but that doesn't work either

Comment: What do you mean "that doesn't work either"?  What doesn't work?  Can't help you if you don't show the code you tried.  The appropriate solution is to match the format of the data, the content-type of the request and the middleware on your server so they are all working on the same type of data for that request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved
I haven't used Multer

On *Server 2* use `Buffer.from()` for get Buffer from your http call (because is an JSON array) and then `fs.writeFile()` or `fs.writeFileSync()` write file on disk

This is the way I used (Server 1):

```
await axios.post('http://localhost:5001/', {
  buffer: fileBuffer,
  name: fileName
})
```

Server 2:

```
const { body } = req // This is the HTTP object, it contains buffer and name
const data = Buffer.from(body.buffer) // Transform array to buffer value
const path = './public/' + body.name // "./public/sample.jpg"

fs.writeFileSync(path, data) // writeFile and writeFileSync also accept Buffer
```